# Enrollment logic for Abandon#

Tags: sql-server

Im trying to find the **Abandon #** metric for the Enrollment data with MS SQL . Quantity of users that began enrollment, did not complete the enrollment within 1 calendar day. Beginning the enrollment will be indicated by **Status Detail = 'NextButton'**. Also I want to exclude the users who began enrollment but their account already exists which is indicated by  **statusDetail ='ExistingAccount'.**

**Logic**: Enrollment attempt that did not complete with a successful enrollment within 1 calendar day.

The Code starts like this with the basic filters

```
            SELECT *
            FROM   Report.rpt.Logs
            WHERE EventName = 'Login' AND EventType='Enrollment'
```

**Actual Data:**

```
+-------------------------+----------------+-----------+------------+----------------------+
|     TransactionDate     |  ServiceLogId  | EventName | EventType  |     StatusDetail     |
+-------------------------+----------------+-----------+------------+----------------------+
| 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | ss@gmail.com   | LOGIN     | Enrollment | NextButton           |
| 2015-05-12 06:53:02.957 | cvbb@gmail.com | LOGIN     | Enrollment | NextButton           |
| 2015-05-12 06:53:38.867 | cvbb@gmail.com | LOGIN     | Enrollment | ExistingAccount      |
| 2015-03-01 06:53:45.187 | abc@gmail.com  | LOGIN     | Enrollment | NextButton           |
| 2015-03-05 06:53:45.187 | vrc@gmail.com  | LOGIN     | Enrollment | NextButton           |
| 2015-04-23 06:53:45.187 | sr@gmail.com   | LOGIN     | Enrollment | NextButton           |
| 2015-04-23 06:55:47.187 | sr@gmail.com   | LOGIN     | Enrollment | Successfully Created |
+-------------------------+----------------+-----------+------------+----------------------+
```

**Expected Results**

```
+--------------------------+----------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|      TransactionDate     |  ServiceLogId  | EventName | EventType  | StatusDetail |
+--------------------------+----------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|  2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | ss@gmail.com   | LOGIN     | Enrollment | NextButton   |
|  2015-03-01 06:53:45.187 | abc@gmail.com  | LOGIN     | Enrollment | NextButton   |
|  2015-03-05 06:53:45.187 | vrc@gmail.com  | LOGIN     | Enrollment | NextButton   |
+--------------------------+----------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good application of a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause. The two `NOT EXISTS` below each filters off one of your criteria.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  @logs AS l
WHERE
  l.EventName = 'LOGIN'
  AND l.EventType = 'Enrollment'
  AND l.StatusDetail = 'NextButton'
  AND NOT EXISTS
(--Filter off Existing Accounts
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    @logs AS s
  WHERE
    s.ServiceLogId = l.ServiceLogId
    AND s.StatusDetail = 'ExistingAccount'
)
  AND NOT EXISTS
(--Filter off logins where enrollment was Successfully Created
 --within 1 calendar day. 
  SELECT
    1
  FROM
    @logs AS s
  WHERE
    s.ServiceLogId = l.ServiceLogId
    AND s.StatusDetail = 'Successfully Created'
    AND CAST(l.TransactionDate AS DATE) = CAST(s.TransactionDate AS DATE)
);
```

Results:

```
+-------------------------+---------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
|     TransactionDate     | ServiceLogId  | EventName | EventType  | StatusDetail |
+-------------------------+---------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
| 2000-01-01 00:00:00.000 | ss@gmail.com  | LOGIN     | Enrollment | NextButton   |
| 2015-03-01 06:53:45.187 | abc@gmail.com | LOGIN     | Enrollment | NextButton   |
| 2015-03-05 06:53:45.187 | vrc@gmail.com | LOGIN     | Enrollment | NextButton   |
+-------------------------+---------------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

**Edit:** Added an additional `WHERE` criteria to only pick up the `NextButton` status for any given user.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is the approach that I was exactly looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to exclude the servicelog data from the query

```
DECLARE @Logs TABLE
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1),
    TransactionDate     datetime,
    ServiceLogId    varchar(100),
    EventName   varchar(100),
    EventType   varchar(50),
    StatusDetail    varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO  @Logs(TransactionDate, ServiceLogId, EventName, EventType,StatusDetail)VALUES('2000-01-01 00:00:00.000' , 'ss@gmail.com'   , 'LOGIN'     , 'Enrollment' , 'NextButton')
INSERT INTO  @Logs(TransactionDate, ServiceLogId, EventName, EventType,StatusDetail)VALUES('2015-05-12 06:53:02.957' , 'cvbb@gmail.com' , 'LOGIN'     , 'Enrollment' , 'NextButton')
INSERT INTO  @Logs(TransactionDate, ServiceLogId, EventName, EventType,StatusDetail)VALUES('2015-05-12 06:53:38.867' , 'cvbb@gmail.com' , 'LOGIN'     , 'Enrollment' , 'ExistingAccount')
INSERT INTO  @Logs(TransactionDate, ServiceLogId, EventName, EventType,StatusDetail)VALUES('2015-03-01 06:53:45.187' , 'abc@gmail.com' , 'LOGIN'     , 'Enrollment' , 'NextButton')
INSERT INTO  @Logs(TransactionDate, ServiceLogId, EventName, EventType,StatusDetail)VALUES('2015-03-05 06:53:45.187' , 'vrc@gmail.com'  , 'LOGIN'     , 'Enrollment' , 'NextButton')
INSERT INTO  @Logs(TransactionDate, ServiceLogId, EventName, EventType,StatusDetail)VALUES('2015-04-23 06:53:45.187' , 'sr@gmail.com'   , 'LOGIN'     , 'Enrollment' , 'NextButton')
INSERT INTO  @Logs(TransactionDate, ServiceLogId, EventName, EventType,StatusDetail)VALUES('2015-04-23 06:55:47.187' , 'sr@gmail.com'   , 'LOGIN'     , 'Enrollment' , 'Successfully Created' )

SELECT * FROM @Logs l
WHERE l.StatusDetail ='NextButton'
AND l.ServiceLogId NOT IN(SELECT ServiceLogId FROM @Logs l2 WHERE l2.StatusDetail IN ('ExistingAccount','Successfully Created' ))
```

Comment: This doesn't cover the "did not complete with a successful enrollment within 1 calendar day" timing requirement.

Comment: can you add sample data in that example and your expected result?

Comment: Same data, same expected result. If you add, for instance, a month to the date in the final row, it no longer meets the "within one day" requirement, but this query (as originally posted, anyway) will still filter that user off because it is only filtering by status, not by relative dates.